# Is it possible to get a list of Linux servers I am currently logged into?

Tags: linux, networking, login

At my workplace, we have a number of Linux machines on an isolated network, and I occasionally need to determine which of them I am logged in to. This can be a pain because I usually have a large number of multi-tab terminal windows strewn across two monitors, four gnome workspaces, and sometimes multiple login sessions.

I do have a list of most of the machines I use and something like `$(rsh $M ps -wef | grep username | wc -l)` usually works, but it is slow and not robust. I am hoping there is some Unix utility or directory service that keeps track of all network logins and that I can simply check that and `grep` for my username. I am surprised that I have not been able to find this by searching on Google and I suspect that no such utility exists, but I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, and showing whatever names or shortcuts you use when you specify the server to ssh:

```
ps --no-heading -o args -C ssh
```

returns:

```
ssh server1
ssh server2
ssh server1
```

(see man ssh_config for details of defining shortcuts)

Comment: Thanks. All good answers, but for my particular workflow, this one is definitely the most straightforward, and it works perfectly for me after a little tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such utility, but one thing that might get you closer is looking at `netstat` and checking that the destination is in a list of servers and that the process name is ssh.

Also, don't use rsh unless you like getting your machines compromised.

Edit: More info

netstat lists all currently active network connections to anywhere, given the correct flags. (`man netstat`). Approaching your problem from another direction, have you tried organizing your connections more? I'd use `screen` and name each window in screen with the server you're connecting to (Using `^a,A`.)

Comment: netstat seems like it does almost exactly what I need - it shows a list of servers, most of which I am logged in to, plus a few extras that I'm not sure about. Is there some caveat to this program that I should know about?

These machines are just on a local network, they are not connected to the internet.

Comment: I actually had my PS1 variable set to put the host name in the terminal window title. I have no idea why, but that stopped working at some point, which certainly makes this whole thing more frustrating. I'm thinking I can use netstat's options and some miscellaneous unix tools to print out my list - is there any reason that shouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Accurate, but quicker than netstat:

```
lsof -i -a -c ssh
```

It returns data like this:

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     15072  myuser    3u  IPv4 8118099      0t0  TCP self:51941->server1:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     26242  myuser    3u  IPv4 9051562      0t0  TCP self:35685->server2:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     26249  myuser    3u  IPv4 9051889      0t0  TCP self:46646->server1:22 (ESTABLISHED)
```

So you can strip out the list of server names like this:

```
lsof -i -a -c ssh | sed -n -e 's/.*>//' -e 's/:.*//p' | sort -u
```

which returns:

```
server1
server2
```